# Dr Memory crash in Visual Studio with "WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000409"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, dr-memory

I made a Node class and tried to implement a simple tree structure using C++. I tested the code, visual studio was able to compile and output the expected results. However, when I tried Dr Memory to check memory leak, Dr Memory always crash at certain points, including:
1) in the Node class constructor "col = vec[0].size()"
2) in the distance function "col = vec[0].size()"

If I kept those lines, visual studio can compile and output the right thing, however, Dr Memory crash... If I commented those lines, Dr Memory works... So I am quite confused what part went wrong, is the nodes on the heap? or the vector? or Dr Memory... Thank you

```
// node class
class Node {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> board;
    int row;
    int col;
    Node(vector<vector<int>> &vec): board(vec) {
        row = vec.size();
        col = vec[0].size();
    }
    Node(Node *&node): board(node->board) {}
};

// calculate distance
int distance(v2_i &vec) {
    int ans = 0;
    int row = vec.size();
    int col = vec[0].size();
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++) ans += abs(vec[i][j]-(i*row+j+1));
    }
    return ans;
}

// main function
int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> startBoard = input_txt();
    Node *node_1 = new Node(startBoard);
    Node *node_2 = new Node(node_1);

    cout << distance(node_2->board) << endl;

    delete node_1;
    delete node_2;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `input_txt()` added items to the vector? `col = vec[0].size();` will be UB if the vector is empty. You probably want to replace `col = vec[0].size();` with `if (row > 0)  col = vec[0].size(); else col = 0;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I am sure input_txt() return the correct 2d vector. I did not post that function in the original question

Comment: So the "vec" is a 2d vector, thus the visual studio can compile and I tried to print this 2d vector, the result is correct. However, I am not sure why Dr Memory didn't work... Is that because I created nodes on heap...?

Comment: I would still correct for this potential bug. In `Node::Node(vector<vector<int>> &vec)` and `int distance(v2_i &vec)`.

Comment: I believe that is all we can help for the code presented.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix that bug you mentioned. I am still quite confused why everything was fine in visual studio, however, Dr Memory crashed...

Comment: After you fixed the bug (in every place) does `Dr Memory` still crash?

Comment: Actually based on your suggestion, I found out an interesting fact.... I tried to output the vec.size(), from visual studio, vec.size() = 4, however, from DrMemory, vec.size() = 0...

Comment: So when you use `DrMemory` your vector is empty.

Comment: So yes, I really appreciate your advice, I should add some if statement to check the vec.size(), however, now the problem is the result from visual studio and DrMemory is different... I guess the problem is still the dynamic memory? since I made all nodes on heap

Comment: ***I guess the problem is still the dynamic memory?***  I say no. `DrMemory` just exposes the potential bug (blindly assuming the vector is not empty) that you have in your code. I believe it is a good thing that this type of bug is caught by DrMemory.

Comment: You are right... So the problem should be the output of input_txt()... I tried to change the project working directory back to project default, however it still didn't work...

Comment: The problem was the working directory. When I modified the working directory of Dr Memory to the same directory as VS, it worked. Thanks

Comment: I am surprised you replied after so long. Glad you got this working..

Comment: Thanks for your help!! And I am also surprised that you replied so quickly after so long, haha